# Package 'python-tk' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying it install **Tinker** on my **Ubuntu 17.04** but some how it does not seem working, I have used all these command on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install upgrade    
sudo apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Every time I am getting :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-tk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-tk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Are you sure its not already installed? try running python interpreter  with `import tkinter ` if that fails check out http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html

Comment: which python version are you using ? for python3.6 you can try this `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk`. and one more idea,  are your repositories properly configured?

Comment: Since this my first program with python, I exactly have no idea, but `python -V` gives me `Python 2.7.13` and `python3 -V` giving me `Python 3.5.3`

Comment: @Mick_ I followed the URL you provided and installed `Active-Tcl` & `Active-Python` problem still remains the same :(

Comment: Check your sources.list in `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and verify if they are correct for your distro. You can generate a new `sources.list` content here - https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ . Also consider using LTS version of Ubuntu as the 17.04 is not supported anymore if i remember correctly.